# UPI Integration using Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, integration, upi

I am facing issues with UPI transactions. I am opening UPI app via intent using uri with required data but for some upi id I am getting payment failed. IF I am trying to pay (with upi apps like bhima etc) on same UPI Id in which I am getting payment failed via intent the transactions are getting success.

So I need help in this. IF any one have any solution.

Code:

```
val paymentUri = Uri.Builder().scheme("upi").authority("pay").appendQueryParameter("pa", upiId).appendQueryParameter("pn", name).appendQueryParameter("tn", tn).appendQueryParameter("am", upiAmount).appendQueryParameter("tr", orderId).appendQueryParameter("cu", "INR").build()

    Log.d("uri", paymentUri.toString())
    val upiPayIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, paymentUri)
    val chooser = Intent.createChooser(upiPayIntent, "Pay with")
    if (null != chooser.resolveActivity(context.packageManager)) {
        return chooser
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(context, "No UPI app found, please install one to continue", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    return null
}
```

Expecting success result of all the type of transactions.